# Having trouble with Swipe Tabs in Android Studio

Tags: android, tabs, swipe

App is not responding as soon I run it. My IDE is the latest version of Android Studio. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVahIc8yENk) tutorial. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.sime.swipetabs;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar mActionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = mActionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 =  mActionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3 = mActionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Tab 3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        mActionBar.addTab(tab1);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab2);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Comment: use `TabLayout` instead *Actionbar* tabs see this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: can you suggest from where should i learn TabLayout  , iam a beginner i want to learn core concept how it work where should i learn in detail i form the page i could not understand how it work i need tutorial but most of them doest not tell how it work ....... can you suggest me where should i learn from

Comment: I  posted link to tutorial if you see..

Comment: its is your website

Comment: Nope it simple tutorial, written by some other author

Comment: can you tell me from where do you learn android  ..i am asking you because i didn't go collage and i learn by own self .it is diffcult to found consistense  tutoiral

Comment: You can watch Vedio of Android development from coursera, YouTube like website

Comment: i am watching slide nerd video its free.....their are also paid tutorials from that website do i buy it

Comment: what is your optinon from learning from collage